# I deleted a bounty answer by mistake

Tags: support, bounty, deleted-answers

I know it looks foolish, and it certainly is, but it appears I deleted an answer for which I had been awarded a 50 rep. bounty on SO.

I realised my blunder when I saw my reputation had just gone down 50 points!

Is there any way I can undelete my answer and retrieve the bounty I lost?

The answer I deleted had not been up-voted, nor accepted. But the bounty *had* been awarded.

It seems I went on a cleaning-up-old-posts spree without paying too much attention.

Comment: If you deleted it yourself, you can also *undelete* it again.

Comment: @MartijnPieters well, it appears not to be the case: as it is an old post, it does not show in "deleted recent answers"

Comment: But it *does* show in your reputation history, provided you check the little checkbox at the bottom to show removed posts.

Comment: It'll be gone now that I undeleted the post. :-P

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can always undelete posts you deleted yourself. I've found the post and undeleted it for you, you'll have those 50 points back when the system recalculates your reputation.

In future, if you don't know what post it was you deleted, you can easily find it back in your reputation history. Just check the *show removed posts* checkbox at the bottom of the page; you'll see an entry at the time of deletion recording the loss of reputation, which links you to the answer:

> [image: 50 point loss due to removed post with link]

There is also a list of [deleted answers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/deleted-answers/current) in your answers tab.

Comment: thanks, I could see the post through the reputation history. However: is the rep gone for good?

Comment: @Manube: no, the rep will be back with the next recalculation.