# Are reputation giveaways allowed?

Tags: discussion, questions, reputation, bounty

In essence are users allowed to create bounties with the sole purpose of randomly giving it away to the first person (or person x) who answers, regardless of if the answer is correct or not?

What are the policies relating to this? Is it frowned upon? I've read the guidelines and unless I missed it, I have not seen any discussion relating to doing this.

This seems like a good way to get users who you see trying hard a boost to being able to access more features but at the same time looks like an easy way to give trolls an accidental boost. So i'm really curious how others feel about this and what the current guidelines say about it.

Comment: What you do with your rep is entirely up to you. Why would you want to do that, though? Bounty system is designed to attract attention to posts that otherwise would go unnoticed, or increase your chances of getting a thoughtful and thorough answer. Why donate rep if you do not want to choose whose answer is correct? That said, you can always leave it pending, and the bounty will be distributed according to guidelines

Comment: Honestly I don't know why someone would want to do that. But I just had that idea and realised i've never seen it discussed. I mean maybe someone out there has so many points they don't need that they would just want to give it away.

Comment: Actually, some of the users with high rep do that. But they usually do that to help out a question, there is no point in *just* doing a giveaway. That said, there is a good read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307512/top-generous-users-users-that-spend-their-reputation-in-bounties

Comment: Oh I never meant to just do it. I was more curious as to what the thoughts on the subject was and if there was any rules about it. That being said I don't understand why this subject is being given a negative rep in voting.

Comment: It's because meta is a bit different: voting here represents how many people agree with you or disagree, basically a thumbs up/down. Note the lack of reputation change due to that. You will at least get an answer for "is it frowned upon?" :)

Comment: It looks like it is allowed: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349555/a-yaakov-ellis-inspired-meta-se-poetry-contest-write-poems-win-rep the only concern I heard from a CM is that we kept that question "hostage" on the featured tab for 2 to 3 weeks so all the bounties could be set and awarded.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289780/is-there-a-way-to-donate-reputation and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297338/maybe-add-posibility-to-just-pass-fast-bounty-to-other-post-to-show-your-gra

Comment: Sometimes, it is not so random (reputation points laundering through the bounty system (to protect reputation points gained in voting tings)).

Comment: If I saw an incorrect answer I would immediately downvote it.  I would also flag the question, while the bounty was active, for moderator attention.  I would vote to delete the incorrect answer.

Comment: @SecurityHound it pays to be very precise in your terminology in this case. You should not flag because there is an incorrect answer, but if it is a troll answer just to reap the bounty then yes.

Comment: I consider the behavior being asked about to be abuse.  If a moderator doesn’t agree then that’s fine.  I would report the behavior, I see bounties being used to block the community, from closing questions all too often

Answer (score 5):

This isn’t the lottery: Stack Overflow has standards that answers must meet. If a bounty did go to a troll answer somehow, the troll answer would be deleted and the bounty reputation removed from their account, which is always what happens when [a bountied answer is deleted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296039/6083675). (Any reputation changes from votes on the answer would also be reversed.)

I’m not sure that the bounty would stick around long enough to be able to be awarded as it seems pretty likely that it would be flagged and refunded by a moderator. You’re supposed to act based off the usefulness and quality of posts, not other factors.